# How to test an inner class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, inner-class

I did my research, but could not find a clear guidelines on how to test an inner class.
This is my inner class:

```
public class ExistingAccountResult{
    public String salesforceaccountid {get;set;}
    public String status {get;set;}
    public Boolean includeinfunnel {get;set;}
    public String masterid {get;set;}
    public string accountid{get;set;}        
}
```

How do I call it from my test class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create an instance of inner class and populate its properties by test data:

```java
OuterClass.ExistingAccountResult result = new OuterClass.ExistingAccountResult();
result.salesforceaccountid = // testId
result.status = // testStatus 
result.includeinfunnel = // testData
result.masterid = // testId
result.accountid = // testId
```

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but getting errors. I tried: 
OuterClass.ExistingAccountResult result = OuterClass.ExistingAccountResult();
but getting Invalid Type OuterClass.ExistingAccountResult

Comment: I also added new : OuterClass.ExistingAccountResult result = new OuterClass.ExistingAccountResult();   , but same error

Comment: @IvoDimov I am sure your outer class is not named as `OuterClass`. Use the exact name of the class that wraps your inner class.

Comment: which error? I assume your inner class has an explicit constructor(s)? If so, add a default non-private constructor .

Comment: Got it. I had a type as well. It is working now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info Oleh, I also had a typo as well for my outer class, causing me the issue. Thanks

Comment: You`re welcome)